# Intermittent Lag Issues

Tags: league-of-legends

I have looked around quite a bit and still haven't found a solution to my problem.

I am having lag spike issues and I don't know what to do at this point.

It seems intermittent, in which it will be fine for 4 or 5 seconds and then pings can reach 45k. It isn't just in video games, it is the connection in general.

I have flushed the dns, renewed my IP, reinstalled my WLAN/LAN drivers, checked my computer's network for usage via netgear genie and monitored it.

I ran in cmd prompt ping google.com -t and found out that every 5 or 6 seconds I would spike up to 800ms in ping. I then ran ping 192.168.0.1 -t to find my ping to my router will jump to 70 ms after periods of 1 - 6 ms.

The problem began about two weeks ago, I didn't do any updates or install any odd programs that may have cause it, I have checked the rest of my drivers within the last 2 days and fixed any that needed updating.

I don't think the issue is performance bottleneck, I have an i7-4700MQ, GTX 765m, and an mSata with 16GB RAM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be a geographical issue. Where do you live (apartment/house) and what is your route to the next node (you are right next to it or live a few kilometres away with a lot of residences in between)?

Comment: let your provider check it and probably repair cable going to your home

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general network troubleshooting.  Since this problem isn't specific to a game, this isn't in our purview.  You might try SuperUser; they may be able to help.

Comment: Maybe you have bad connection with your region server. I recommend you to make account in different region and to check ping from that account.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact that it appears to be the internet connection and not your computer, I recommend having a chat with your ISP.

Depending on your internet type and/or location, there are many thing that could be affecting your internet quality.

For instance, in the routing to your house, there could be a switch that is causing packet loss, or that has too much traffic and is slowing down,

If you're on wireless internet your house could have a poor signal due to any number of reasons, which would kill your internet speeds